# how to locate properties id number in xcode error

Tags: xcode, swift

how can I find where 0x7fd60501d8e0 is referring to

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver
>   (<"appname".MenuViewController: 0x7fd60501d8e0>) has no segue with
>   identifier 'menuToPost'

Comment: 0x7fd60501d8e0 is the address of the object, which isn't particularly useful. Instead you should search your project (⇧⌘F) for the string "menuToPost" which is being used incorrectly for a segue.

Comment: How many classes `MenuViewController` do you have? ;-)

Comment: To learn how to debug a crash please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1